# Access variable outside foreach Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I'm trying to access my variable but it is giving me an empty array.

example:

```
var data = [];
$.each(files, function (index, file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
        data.push({
            name: file.name,
            file: evt.target.result
        });
    }
});

console.log(data)
```

At this moment data is an empty array. When i put the console.log in the foreach it is returning my data. How can i return and acces the data that is filled outside of the foreach?

Comment: ti is because `FileReader.readAsDataURL` is an async method

Comment: because console.log(data) executing before the reader request. reader is asynchronus.

Comment: the variable is probably empty, because the `onload` callback has not fired yet, and the `handleReaderLoad` function hasn't run yet.

Comment: See my updated answer which will console.log only when the last file is read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleReaderLoad` will be called in an **asynchrounous** fashion. You can keep track of the number of files and log in the `onload` when the file count is complete

```
 var data = [];
 var fileCount = files.length;
 var currentCount = 0;
 $.each(files, function(index, file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);

     function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
         data.push({
             name: file.name,
             file: evt.target.result
         });
         currentCount++;
         if (currentCount == fileCount) {
             console.log(data);
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! now i can have a great weekend! ;-)

Comment: @kazehaya, yes, have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `FileReader` but it's obvious that method `readAsDataURL`is called asynchronous.

Your `onload` method is not called inmediatly, your code flow continues without waiting for that to trigger so at the point `console.log(data)` is reached, data is not filled yet.

> JavaScript is a single-threaded language. This means that invoking a long-running process blocks all execution until that process completes. UI elements are unresponsive, animations pause, and no other code in the app can run. The solution to this problem is to avoid synchronous execution as much as possible.
>
> One way to do this is to have a function execute at a later time, as with event handlers, which are invoked after another call has raised an event. Callback functions are another kind of asynchronous processing, because they call back into the code that initiated the process.

[Asynchronous programming in JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick.

```
var data = [];
$.each(files, function (index, file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = handleReaderLoad;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
    data.push({
        name: file.name,
        file: evt.target.result
    });
    if(files.length == data.length)
        console.log(data);
}
```